# Cheerio giving strange results

Tags: node.js, cheerio

This is a simple  cheerio app. The  tag has a class named product-link and i want to access its href, but when i console log this, i am not getting any html. Can anyone shade a light on what is going on and how to get the data i want from this??

```
let holder = $('.product-link');
console.log(holder);
```

Result->

```
initialize {
  options:
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xml: false,
     decodeEntities: true },    
  _root:
   initialize {
     '0':
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
        children: [Array],
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null },
     options:
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xml: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     length: 1,
     _root: [Circular] },
  length: 0,
  prevObject:
   initialize {
     '0':
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
        attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
        'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
        'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
        children: [Array],
        parent: null,
        prev: null,
        next: null },
     options:
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xml: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     length: 1,
     _root: [Circular] } }
```

Comment: were you able to solve this issue ?

Comment: @JP. i think i ended up using cheerio with Puppeteer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone still facing the same issues, if you don't get proper HTML when using cheerio, you can use Puppeteer to emulate the browser, open the webpage until everything is loaded, and parse the HTML from puppeteer using Cheerio.

Answer (score 1):

cheerio has an API similar to that of jQuery. so when you call this function `$('selector')` cheerio will return you an object with a lot of methods and fields to get attributes or find child nodes etc. So that's why it does not return the html. however, if you want to see the underlining HTML then you can use `$('selector').html()`.

If you want to access an attribute you can use `attr()` method.

so now your code will be

```js
const holder = $('.product-link');
const href = holder.attr('href');
```

You can reference the documentation from

https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

https://api.jquery.com/ (since cheerio is designed to be similar to jQuery)

Answer (score -1):

Hey i solved my above issue in callback function of request module. Pass the body of result to cheerio like:

```
request.get(URL, (err, result) => {
  const $ = await cheerio.load(result.body);
});
```

I was making a mistake like this:

```
const $ = await cheerio.load(result); // dont use this line
```